# How are class variables handled when methods in multiprocessing.Process access them?

Tags: python

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, my_val):
        self.my_val = my_val

    def process_one(self):
        ... do something, maybe access self.my_val


    def do_work(self):
        sub_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_one)

        ... now do work and maybe access self.my_val

        sub_process.join()
```

How is the variable handled by the two different processes (the calling one and the one spawned)? Is the variable accessible across the processes? Is this safe if only one ever writes to the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Call to `self.process_one` can be viewed as `process_one(self)`, so `Process` has to pickle the `self`. It depends on particular attributes if this pickling goes well.

Nevertheless the 'self' in the other process is a separate instance and takes the state of 'self' during creation of the spawned process.

Comment: So by this do you mean that the view of `self.my_val` within `process_one()` will be whatever it was when the process was started, i.e. if `do_work()` mutates the value of `self.my_val` after `process_one()` was started that `process_one()` will only ever see the original value?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. After `start` the new process is a fully independant process with its own set of variables. Unless you use specific synchronizations, the variables in both processes will have a different life. Here is a simple example demonstrating it:

```
import multiprocessing

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, my_val):
        self.my_val = my_val

    def process_one(self):
        print('start')
        for i in range(10):
            self.my_val += 1
        print('done', self.my_val)


    def do_work(self):
        sub_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_one)
        sub_process.start()
        sub_process.join()

def run():
    c = MyClass(5)
    c.do_work()
    print('Caller', c.my_val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

It displays:

```
start
done 15
Caller 5
```

proving that the object in main process has not changed.